# What to disable on my second router as switch?

Tags: networking, router, switch, wired-networking

I'm extending my network coverage to the basement and I took the dust off my old router and am now converting it to a network switch. Wireless will probably be turned off so that it only support wired LAN connections.

Following tutorials online, I did not change anything on my main router. I played around with a few settings on the second router: turned DHCP server off and changed the IP to something different than my main router. Now because the information is not very clear when reading different tutorials, I am confused as to what to do with certain settings.

On my second router should:

- NAT be disabled?
- firewalls be disabled? Firewall options on the router are IPv6 SPI Firewall Protection, IPv4 SPI Firewall Protection, Filter Anonymous Internet Requests, Filter Multicast, Filter Internet NAT Redirection for IPv4 Internet Only, IPSec Passthrough, PPTP Passthrough, L2TP Passthrough.

Correct me if I'm wrong but it makes sense for me to disable all of those options because the main router handles all the security features already. As a note, my main router is the Asus RT-AC68U and my secondary router is the Linksys E2500. Might not be very important but I should also mention that I'm using my second router as a wireless access point at the moment but that's only because I am still waiting for ethernet cables to ship. I will probably turn wireless off to improve performance through LAN once I get the cables.

Comment: I generally turn off DHCP on the second router so I have one network address range that is handled by the first/main router

Comment: First and foremost, flash [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/linksys/linksys_e2500_v1) to it, else you're running a router with exploitable code since it's missing 6yrs worth of security patches _(last OEM image: 2014.04.17)_.  OpenWrt will also allow you to assign the WAN port to the LAN interface, and among other things, the ability to run ~1,000 or so extra programs.  As to NAT, it's not needed and wouldn't be of concern if you assigned the WAN port to the LAN interface; there's also no need to firewall any of the traffic since it's your LAN traffic.

Comment: You are right for cases of the product at version 1 or 2, however, mine in version 3 and the last update was in 2018. I've never heard of OpenWrt before, never knew you can flash your router with a custom rom! I'll most certainly take a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *only* want to use the second router as a switch, simply connect the first router to one of the ethernet "outs" on the second router. The router automatically acts as a switch for those connections.

As for what to disable - your router's input from your modem is not connected, so none... or very few of the options will be applied.

After scouring Google for more info regarding your specific setup, it looks like the E2500 can't function as an access point. So, my initial advice was correct. Plug the first router into one of the LAN ports and you're all set!

Comment: Thank you. But I'm just wondering if disabling those options might improve performance, since this router isn't really high end.Now that I think of it though, am I correct to say that those firewall/NAT options are only for setups using WAN? If that's the case, then disabling those options won't do anything to my LAN to LAN setup I guess?

Comment: Exactly! I'm sorry if my explanation wasn't clear.

The options won't do anything if your using it as a switch (LAN to LAN).

Answer (score 2):

The only option you need to disable is DHCP. You should disable as much as you can to save cpu cycles.

While they work in a pinch, consumer grade routers don't typically make great switches because they are actually comprised of multiple ports which are bridged together in software to behave like a switch. Unfortunately this is cPU intensive and they can slow down all devices connected to or through it.

Comment: Makes sense. The long term solution would be to buy an actual switch then.

Comment: I'm somewhat sure _most_ consumer grade routers actually have hardware switching. Depending on model, the software bridge might be only between the switch & the Wi-Fi AP (ethernet ports always switched independently of the OS), or it might be what _activates_ the hardware acceleration (if the drivers make use of Linux bridge offload features).